# Search number in array C

Tags: arrays, c

For some reason, the option does not work for me when I enter a number that is not in the array. And at the same time, how can I do it when, for example, I enter

```
Enter the 1st element (-1 for the end of the entry): 1
Enter the 1st element (-1 for the end of the entry): 3
Enter the 1st element (-1 for the end of the entry): 4
Enter the 1st element (-1 for the end of the entry): 6
Enter the 1st element (-1 for the end of the entry): 3
Enter the 1st element (-1 for the end of the entry): -1
```

and when I enter to search for the position of the number 3, they print the last position, that is, that the number 3 is in the 5th position, and not in the 2nd position

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 
 double a[100];
 int n;
 int i,element,pos=0;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 printf("Enter %d. element (-1 for end): ",i+1);
 scanf("%lf",&a[i]);
 
 if(a[i]==-1) break;
}
printf("Enter number for search: ");
   scanf("%d",&element);

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
     if(a[i]==element)
     {
       printf("The number %d was entered as %d number per line.", element, i+1);
       return 0;
     }
   }

   printf("%d not found.", element);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` you invoked *undefined behavior* here by using the value of uninitialized `n`.

Comment: "I enter 1,3,4,5,3,2" are the commas part of your input?

Comment: Why are you searching for a `int` value from the `double` array?

Comment: @MikeCAT I changed some things so the entry should look like, and I'm just learning, so there are mistakes like you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You invoked *undefined behavior* by using the value of uninitialized non-static local variable `n` in the loop conditions `i<n`. You should use the number of elements of the array instead of `n` in the first loop, and set `n` to `i` after the first loop.
- To find the last occurance of a number, you should search from the last element of the array.
- It should be natural to use `double` for `element` because the elements of the array `a` are `double`.
- You should check the return values of `scanf()` to see if it successfully read what is expected for safety.

Fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
int main() {

  double a[MAX],element;
  int n;
  int i,pos=0;
  for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
  {
    printf("Enter %d. element (-1 for end): ",i+1);
    if(scanf("%lf",&a[i])!=1)
    {
      fputs("read error\n", stderr);
      return 1;
    }

    if(a[i]==-1) break;
  }
  n=i;
  printf("Enter number for search: ");
  if(scanf("%lf",&element)!=1)
  {
    fputs("read error\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  for(i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    if(a[i]==element)
    {
      printf("The number %g was entered as %d number per line.", element, i+1);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  printf("%g not found.", element);
  return 0;
}
```